# Sharing workspace files between two machines - perforce

Tags: version-control, perforce

I have set up a client workspace in an windows machine [machine 1]. I have pointed the directory

```
C:\SomeDir
```

to map to the remote branch

```
//branch/component/...
```

and I sync my files to the local directory.

I, then, copy over my workspace files to another windows machine [machine 2]. I create a new workspace in [machine 2] and point to the directory that I have copied over from [machine 1] which again maps to the same remote branch.

I would like to use the workspace created on [machine 2] to check-in and do my work. But perforce does not recognize the files.

Is there a way for me to do the above?

Answer (score 0):

Don't copy the files from machine to machine yourself.

Instead, issue the 'p4 sync' command on each machine, and let the Perforce software copy the files to each machine.

Perforce will keep track of which files you have on each machine, and will only copy the necessary files to the machine each time you sync that workspace.

Here's a good place to start: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/intro/index.html

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I do not want to sync the files in machine 2. I want to copy over the files from machine 1 into machine 2 and use them. Is there a way to get perforce recognize the files?

Comment: @RajkumarP Why don't you want to sync the files in machine 2?  If you need to share unsubmitted changes between machine 1 and machine 2, you could create separate Perforce clients and use shelving.  Ohterwise if you absolutely must go through with your apparent goal of misusing Perforce by manually copying the source tree from machine 1 to machine 2, you will need to through with it fully by manually copying any changes you make on machine 2 *back* to machine 1.

Answer (score 0):

Not even sure why you have machine 1 (and workspace (ws) 1) since you aren't doing anything on it other than copying the contents of ws 1 from machine 1 to machine 2

I would just create a workspace on machine 2 and work there.